# log4j warning after `homebrew install zookeeper`

Tags: java, log4j, homebrew, apache-zookeeper

I'm running Mac OS X 10. I just did `brew install zookeeper`.

Then I created `/usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg` based on `/usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo_sample.cfg`.

Then `zkServer start` works just fine.

But, when trying to connect to Zookeeper from Clojure, which uses the Zookeeper Java client, I get this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

My `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, zklog
log4j.appender.zklog = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.zklog.File = /usr/local/var/log/zookeeper/zookeeper.log
log4j.appender.zklog.Append = true
log4j.appender.zklog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.zklog.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

So, my questions are:

1. What is a reasonable log4j configuration for my situation?
2. What could homebrew do, out of the box, to prevent this warning from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, there are two `log4j.properties` files involved. [One is created by Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/zookeeper.rb#L37) and [gets written to `/usr/local/etc/zookeeper/log4j.properties`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/zookeeper.rb#L124). This file is not the cause of the error message above.

The other `log4j.properties` file is particular to your (my) application. So, to answer part 1 of the question, create a `log4j.properties` file on the classpath of the Clojure app, such as in the `src` directory.

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, A1
log4j.logger.user=DEBUG
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c: %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
```

I built this by starting with https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging and adding the last line.

To answer part 2, Homebrew does not and should not have anything to do with how a Clojure application sets up its logging.